# WordPress drop down menu in responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on http://pranayam.mwancloud.com/. My drop down menu is working great on large screens up to three levels. But there is some issue on the small screen devices you can check as well.

On the main menu:  CLASSES > Yoga > contain three pages which I am trying to show. When I click on "Yoga" and the menu should drop but it is not working. I tried many things but nothing went helpful.

I will be thankful if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: you want to move menus down to yoga?

Comment: Yeah exactly the same thing as other menu items

Answer (score 0):

[image]Just add one different class to `ul` of yoga part and give below css for it

```
ul.something {
 margin:0px !important;
}
```

See i mark that `ul` in picture give different class for it.

**EDITED**

sorry for that i don't know about wordress.

add below css in your code

```
li#menu-item-145 ul{
 margin:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't add any class. The ul is being generated by the WordPress menu itself.

Comment: When I click on Yoga the drop down don't even appear but closes to the top item

Comment: I did that I is not working.. When I click on yoga to show the list it even closes us to top item.. But when I click on "Yoga" for 2 seconds then it displays the list items.

Comment: The CSS for ul and li is generated by it self and I can't add any class in ul or li. but I can write css for it. I can also write jquery. I am trying on it from 2 days before the weekend. I got it to the point it is now but having issues for showing it

Comment: can you please show image of it how it looking adding above css in code

Comment: it's working when adding above css last one. but there is problem is that this effect is comming on hover and in mobile have to click so that's why you have to keep click it 1 or 2 sec

Comment: Yes I got it. I got images what I want but not finding any place from where I can upload it to show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117573/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-sagar-kodte).